# JavaScript errors when using IE9 behind a corporate proxy

Tags: support

I am not sure whether or not this is the right area to raise this but it looks like there may be an issue with the main sites script.

When I go to ask a question on the main site (the meta site is working fine) all the formatting and preview functionality is not working. When I look at developr tools in ie (I am using IE9) I get the following:

[image]

I am behind a corporate proxy which seems to be blocking quant.js and scorecardresearch.com but as theylooks like some sort of advert / stats tracking code I wouldn't have thought it would be causing the errors.

[image]

The ask a question page looks like the following:

[image]

Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: Looks like `stub.en.js` has not loaded properly - did you clear the cache? Might be the proxy is caching a corrupt version of the file.

Comment: @Oded I've just checked the request for stub.en.js and sure enough it is getting a 'valid' response but it is not the javascript file. Instead it's a status page from the proxy firewall saying the file has been downloaded but needs to be scanned. Must be an internal issue with the corporate network I'm on. Thanks for your help. I'll raise the issue with them. If you repost your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct to 'close' the question.

Comment: You poor bugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the initial error in the console, it appears that `stub.en.js` has not loaded properly.

Did you clear the cache? Might be the proxy is caching a corrupt version of the file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It looks like it's an internal problem with the proxy that is blocking that script.